# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. mapping(uint => product) public products;

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

below is my code I am not sure why give me this error.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

// creating the contract
contract Rating {
    
    // creating structure to model the product
    struct Product {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint RatingCount;
    }

    // use mapping to get or fetch the contestant details
    mapping(uint => product) public products;

    // add a public state variable to keep track of product count
    uint public productsCount;

    constructor () public {
        addProduct("Nike");
        addProduct("Adidas");
    }

    // add a function to add product
    // for private variable we use underscore in the start of variable _name
    function addProduct(string memory _name) private {
        productsCount++;
        products[productsCount] = Product(productsCount, _name, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity is case-sensitive.

You have defined a struct named `Product` (uppercase P), but your mapping is using `product` (lowercase p).

**Solution:** Use the correct form `Product`

```
mapping(uint => Product) public products;
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I found the answer the problem is in mapping

```
mapping(uint => product) public products;
```

I mistakenly user small p instead of capital P. This gives me an error while migrating my smart contract because my struct name starts from Capital P (Product).
so instead of small p just change the p to P.

```
mapping(uint => Product) public products;
```